# Como hacer que la etiqueta <br/> sea reconocida en html al ser devuelta de una base de datos?

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando en C# con MVC y estoy guardando texto en SQL server pero necesito hacer saltos de línea así que opte por incluir la etiqueta `<br/>`para realizar los saltos, desde una vista realizo la inserción en la base de dato y de otra vista muestro ese dato, el problema es que me sale el texto con todo y la etiqueta como si formara parte del texto, entonces quisiera saber si alguien sabe cómo resolver este problema que tengo o alguna forma de guardar saltos de línea en SQL server y me los reconozca cuando los muestre en la vista.

`<p class="text-muted">@(Model.textopresentacion)</p>`

En esta etiqueta quiero mostrar el texto con saltos de linea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza [`@Html.Raw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) donde convierter un string and `IHtmlString` y te permitar imprimir etiquetas Html validas:

```
<p class="text-muted">@Html.Raw(Model.textopresentacion)</p>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo :D si me funciono

Answer (score -1):

Podes obtener el contenedor en donde lo queres agregar mediante JQuery y se lo agregas usando .html()

```
textoPresentacion = 'Probando <br/> Texto'

$('#test').html(textoPresentacion);

<p id='test'></p>
```

Obtuve el contendor por su id y usando .html() le agregue lo que queria y se obtiene el siguiente resultado.

```
<p id='test'>Probando <br/> Texto <p>
```